# How to loop through Angular 2 component templates

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ngfor

I am creating a master component which will take in an `@Input(): Object`. Within this object I want to include an array of components, which will, in turn, be looped through using `*ngFor` and the components' templates should be placed within Ionic 2 slides. I have tried to accomplish these many different ways to no avail, any suggestions?

Comment: can you share the code for what you have done so far ??

Comment: if you want some examples on how to use `*ngFor` see this https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-first-look-series-new-angular-2-concepts-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

So i did something similar to what you are attempting. However i had other input values for each component, but they were in a slide with a conditional based on a user interaction.

The first slide had a click event

```
<ion-item (click)="gotoInputDetails(0)"
```

The integer determined which component would be called, so the next click event was

```
<ion-item (click)="gotoInputDetails(1)"
```

Then the click method was like so

```
 gotoInputDetails(input: number) {
/**
 * There is only an idx 0 1 on slides. 
 * idx 1 for slide is based on this.showInput which determines which input edit component to show. *ngIf="showInput === 0"
 * 0 = textbox
 * 1 = select
 * 2 = date
 * 3 = range
 * 4 = toggle 
 */
 this.showInput = input;
 this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
 this.slides.slideTo(1);
}
```

So this will always only slide to the 2nd slider however which component is show is then based off of `this.showInput` so the 2nd slide has all my components like so

```
<ion-slide>
     <!-- Textbox -->
     <page-form-add-input-text *ngIf="showInput === 0"></page-form-add-input-text>
     <!-- Select -->
     <page-form-add-input-select *ngIf="showInput === 1"></page-form-add-input-select>
     <!-- Date -->
     <page-form-add-input-date *ngIf="showInput === 2"></page-form-add-input-date>
     <!-- Range -->
     <page-form-add-input-range *ngIf="showInput === 3"></page-form-add-input-range>
     <!-- Toggle-->
     <page-form-add-input-toggle *ngIf="showInput === 4"></page-form-add-input-toggle>
</ion-slide>
```

So it slides to slide 2 and then the component shown is based on the passed parameter on the click event in the item navigating to the 2nd slide.

Because each component on the slide is fairly complex in my case i wanted to separate the components to each have their own logic. This is a bit different to what you asking with a master component but ... i dunno it works for me, maybe there is a better way.

I was also having an issue where if there were say 4 components and i wanted to navigate to the 4th slide ( 3rd index ) is would slide passed the components before it, so the user would, for a second, see the other components view which i did not want.